# How to know the user create every object without using logging LOGGER in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Now I have 5 models and I want to retrieve objects filtered by the user created specific object

## models.py

for instance this model

```
class FileCategory(models.Model):
    file_type = models.CharField(_('type'), max_length=128)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file_type
```

Now I have an objects with `file_type` equals ABC, ENB, ORJ
and I want to list only the file_types which the request user created only. Is it doable? 
Sure I know I can add user attribute `OneToOne` to user model

Comment: why not to create another model with FileCategory and User as ForeignKeys which will store users who have created specific file types?

Comment: Literally I want for all models.. I thought to add a model 'User_Created' and make it a generic foreign key for all models, but is it efficient ???

Comment: just add a `created_by=models.ForeignKey('django.contrib.auth.models.User')` field on every model where you want to track who created the record.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov I know that there is a log model in django and I saw a list of recent actions in panel but don't know how to use

Comment: @voodoo-burger I said I know it but don't want to add a new attribute in every model

Comment: @A.Raouf I agree with voodo-burger. Adding created_by to every model is simplier, then what you want to do. How many models you need to change?

Comment: @A.Raouf as a possible solution you can create a model with generic relation to any object + foreign key to user but it will be to much overhead for such task.

Comment: Okay I'll take the simpler one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fount to use LogEntry model

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
file_category = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(FileCategory)
logs = LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type=file_category,
                               user__username=request.user.username
                               ).values('object_repr')

FileCategory.objects.filter(name__in=logs)
```

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov This is my solution
I know it is not efficient for performance Thanks for help

Comment: @voodoo-burger This is my solution I know it is not efficient for performance Thanks for help